# Is ALE curve value constant for observations in the same interval?

Tags: machine-learning, interpretation

I have been reading Chapter 8.2 of the [Interpretable Machine Learning](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/ale.html) about Accumulated Local Effects (ALE) plots. It includes the following formula which defines the ALE value for a given value of feature x_j:

[image]

As I understand it, the second term on the right side is mean and it will be constant for all values of x_j. At the same time, the first term will be constant for all value of x_j that end up in the same interval. Based on that, ALE curve should look like a step function.

However, this is not consistent with Figure 8.10 where the function is linear:
[image]

I suppose, there is a mistake in my understanding of ALE curve. What am I missing?